# Export Scss mixins npm package

Tags: npm, sass, package

I want to create an npm package that will contain styles and mixins that are used in various projects. The problem is that when you try to run the script, it does not see mixins and other scss charms, maybe someone did something similar, is it possible at all?

i tried to experiment with compilation packages but nothing worked